# Why is my for loop running over? (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
for i = 1:RGB_size(2) % RGB_size(2) = 1296 //X coords

    for j = 1:1:RGB_size(1) % RGB_size(1) = 964  //Y coords

        if mask(i,j) == 1
        data(next_pixel,:) = [ImgIndex, ImgTake, i, j, RGB(i,j,1), RGB(i,j,2), RGB(i,j,3),... 
            HSIR(i,j,1), HSIR(i,j,2), HSIR(i,j,3)];

        next_pixel = next_pixel + 1; %get next pixel
        end
    end
end
```

But Matlab won't run my code because it says I'm trying to access `mask(965,1)` and my variable mask size is 1296×964. However, I don't see how this is possible. Any thoughts?

`RGB_size` is calculated from a variable called `RGB`, which is the same variable used to create the variable `mask`. I have verified that they are both the same size with the debugger.

Actual error message is:

> `Attempted to access mask(965,1); index out of bounds because size(mask)=[964,1296].`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including how you determine `RGB_size`. As a supplement for your image and mask you can probably use something like `RGB=rand(1296,964,3)`.

Comment: Also, please edit your post to include the actual error message.

Comment: I have added the requested info @Daniel

Comment: With the updated information, isn't the error message clear? Your mask is of size `[964,1296]` and not of size `[1296,964]`. You can not access `mask(965,1)` because it does not exist! You are probably mixing up something when creating the mask.

Comment: I added the actual error message @dasdingonesin

Comment: @Daniel You're right. I'm kind of embarrassed I couldn't figure it out myself. Since you were the first one to get it right, do you want to submit a proper answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: You are also abusing `i` and `j`, which are default variables of imaginary units! Change those indices at least to `ii` and `jj`. If you start working with complex numbers this will waste a LOT of time to debug.

Comment: @Crowley So that's part of why it was taking so long to run! In the end I changed the whole code to avoid the `for` loops. Matlab was crashing. It didn't occur to me that my indexes were also the defaults for imaginary units.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have switched the `i` and `j` index of the mask.